# Use Python 3 in OpenWRT Build System

Tags: python, c++, c, cmake, openwrt

Trying to create OpenWRT build system for `Omega` linux on chip device according to [manual](https://docs.onion.io/omega2-docs/cross-compiling.html) on my Ubuntu 20. Got error below while run `make menuconfig`

```
...
Checking 'python'... failed.
...
Build dependency: Please install Python 2.x
```

My system has `Python 3` while manual asks to install `Python 2`.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Use virtualenv to create an isolated Python2 environment in your system.

Comment: it is not possible to solve problem with Python 3 ?

Comment: Python 3 is not backward compatible.

Comment: Since you're asking in a programming forum here, the answer is to port the code to Python 3. Maybe also file a feature request to do that for you. Alternatively, install Python 2. Why did you tag this with both C and C++ btw, even though there's not a single question aspect concerning either language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Python3 is not backward compatible you need to provide Python2 for installation. Follow this instructions to create an isolated Python2 environment in your system:

1. Install Python2 (add repository if needed):

```
sudo apt install python2
```

2. Install pip (package manager):

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py

sudo python2 get-pip.py
```

3. Install virtualenv:

```
sudo apt install virtualenv
```

4. Create virtual environment for Python2 in your favorite directory (change myenv to your favorite name):

```
virtualenv --python=python2 myenv
```

5. Activation:

```
source myenv/bin/activate
```

6. Deactivation:

```
deactivate
```

You can also install required python packages (if needed) by using pip in your activated environment.